# What is the need to __init__

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class Sink:
    def __init__(self, basin, nozzle):
        self.basin = basin
        self.nozzle = nozzle
```

Why we use or need `__init__` method? Why it isn't the same as the code below?

```
class Sink:
    self.basin = basin
    self.nozzle = nozzle
```

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: `__init__` is execute when you create an instance, the so called class body is executed when the class is defined. Both are useful, but for different reasons.

Comment: In this second case how is the class suppose to know about `basin` and `nozzle`?

Comment: In the second piece of code, `self` isn't defined anywhere. Indeed, it raises a `NameError`, why do you *expect* them to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference : [micropyramid : **init** is contructor](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/#:%7E:text=__init__%20%3A,the%20attributes%20of%20a%20class.)

The function of **init** is for constructing inside of the class. That website is explained the purpose of **init**

> "**init**" is a reseved method in python classes. It is known as a constructor in object oriented concepts. This method called when an object is created from the class and it allow the class to initialize the attributes of a class.

Example of using **init** inside class :

```
class Animal(object):
      def __init__(self, atype, avoice):
          self.type = atype
          self.voice = avoice
      
      def set_type(self):
          #do something in here about type
          if type == "cat":
             return "cat is like walk"
          else:
             return self.type+"is like walk"

      def set_voice(self):
          #do something in here similar with def type
```